# Bershelf and installing updated cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

I've forked the chocolatey-cookbook in an attempt to add the ability to set which user you want to execute the install scripts with.

So, I added to `resources/default.rb`:

```
attribute :user, :kind_of => String
```

and I added to `providers/default.rb`:

```
@current_resource.user = (@new_resource.user)
```

to `load_current_Resource` function so I can then just do

```
user @current_resource.user  if @current_resource.user
```

in the execute blocks it uses to actually install a package.

I thought that would work instead all I'm getting is `undefined method user=` for Chef::Resource::Chocolatey`.

So, what am I doing wrong? I've looked but I can't find anything definitive on how resource attributes are declared and used within the provider and I'm kinda stumped.

EDIT: I added `:user` to the `attr_accessor` in the resource file but that just gave a different error: `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)`

EDIT: 
Ok, I don't know why but for some reason `@current_resource` wasn't being returned from the `load_current_resource` function; I worked that out when I was able to get vagrant to do a full stack trace and realised it was erroring where I was setting the user on the execute block for the install action of the chocolatey provider.

All I did was ensure that it was returned by making sure the last line was `@current_resource`. and now it works, I mean sure it errored but for an entirely different reason.

ok, so that didn't fix it, I suddenly got `undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass` error again.

EDIT:

After logging I found that `@current_resource.user` is not `nil` when I log it in `load_current_resource` but it I think it errors before it gets to the execute script that will run the chocolaty installation of the package.

How is the provider class built? and does `@current_resource` exist in only certain instances?

EDIT:

Ok, so just to see what would happen I changed `@current_resource.user` to `@current_resource.instance_variable_get(:@user)` and it worked, no `undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass` error. Whats going on? 
Why does `@current_resource.instance_variable_get(:@user)` work but not `@current_resource.user`?

Answer (score 1):

So Chef's resource attribute don't work like Ruby's accessors (and you shouldn't mix them). The way to do the set in the provider is `@current_resource.user(@new_resource.user)`. This is because the attribute methods are really optimized for use in the recipe DSL blocks (where you would have something like `user 'foo'`).

Comment: ok, so I changed it to `@current_resource.user(@new_resource.user)` like you suggested but now I'm getting `undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass`.

Comment: Are you creating `current_resource`?

Comment: I am, also I think my problem is similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516424/why-does-the-lwrp-custom-definition-gives-me-undefined-method-for-nilnilclass